# Find all indexed positions in each dimension from a subscripted reference

Tags: matlab, subscript

Is there an elegant way one can retrieved all indexed positions (for each dimension) from a subscripted reference when overloading `subsref`. Let's assume for example array `a = rand(3, 5, 4, 2);`, then following subscripts are equivalent:

```
a()                   <=>    a(:,:,:,:)
a(1, 12)              <=>    a(1, 2, 3, 1)
a(2, :, 5)            <=>    a(2, :, 1, 2)
a(2, 3, end:-5:1)     <=>    a(2, 3, 4, 2), a(2, 3, 3, 1)
a(2, 3, 4, 1, :, 1)   <=>    a(2, 3, 4, 1)   

logic = [false, true, false];
a(logic, 5, 2, 1)     <=>    a(2, 5, 2, 1)
```

What I'm interested in is finding, for each dimension, what unique positions are indexed. From above examples this gives:

```
a()                 =>  idx1 = [1,2,3]; idx2 = [1,2,3,4,5]; idx3 = [1,2,3,4]; idx4 = [1,2];
a(1, 12)            =>  idx1 = [1];     idx2 = [2];         idx3 = [3];       idx4 = [1];
a(2, :, 5)          =>  idx1 = [2];     idx2 = [1,2,3,4,5]; idx3 = [1];       idx4 = [2];
a(2, 3, end:-5:1)   =>  idx1 = [2];     idx2 = [3];         idx3 = [3,4];     idx4 = [1,2];
a(2, 3, 4, 1, :, 1) =>  idx1 = [2];     idx2 = [3];         idx3 = [4];       idx4 = [1];

logic = [false, true, false];
a(logic, 5, 2, 1)   =>  idx1 = [2];     idx2 = [5];         idx3 = [2];       idx4 = [1];
```

The reason I want to do this is a bit complex but for short I have a matlab class storing data in one projection mode, but I still want to be able to access data in other various projection modes (mainly for display purpose). I thus have dependent properties which make on the fly conversion on stored data.

So far, so good, the problem is that for some data coordinates (accumulation points) going from one projection mode to another is ambiguous unless I know on which cut (i.e. which subscript) I am ... Being able to pre-detect one dimension is becoming scalar after the subscript I can be smart and check if I can rework computed value before returning it ... For instance this will avoids having artifacts when plotting data in 1D because in one cut you have to choose one formula and in the other cut another one.

Here is the solution I come up with by overloading `subsref` method and parsing the subscript description structure:

```
classdef TestSubscript < handle

    % Lifetime
    methods
        function [this] = TestSubscript()            
            n = 3; m = 5; k = 4; l = 2;
            this.EAz = rand(n,m,k,l);                        
            this.EEl = rand(n,m,k,l);
        end
    end

    % Really stored values in projection mode 1
    properties(Access=private)        
        EAz;
        EEl;
    end

    % Projection in mode 2 computed on the fly
    properties(Dependent)
        EPhi;
    end
    methods

        % Generic formula
        function [ephi] = get.EPhi(this)
            ephi = (sqrt(2)/2)*(this.EAz + this.EEl); % This is dummy (real formula is more complex and depends on coordinates)
        end

        % Detection of special cuts
        function [varargout] = subsref(this, s)

            % First call built-in to apply generic formula
            [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref', this, s);            
            if ((length(s) ~= 2) || ~strcmp(s(1).type, '.') || ~strcmp(s(1).subs, 'EPhi') || ~strcmp(s(2).type, '()'))
                return;
            end

            % Then find selected positions on each dimension for this.EPhi(....lalala....) before returning value
            ndim = ndims(this.EAz); 
            selectedPositions = cell(1, ndim);
            subscript = s(2).subs;
            scount = length(subscript);
            if (scount == 0)
                % Call like 'r = this.EPhi();'
                for ki = 1:ndim,
                    selectedPositions{ki} = 1:size(this.EAz, ki); 
                end
            else
                % Call like 'r = this.EPhi(...lalalala....);'
                for ki = 1:ndim,
                    if (ki < scount)
                        % Ok subscript really corresponds to current dimension
                        selectedPositions{ki} = subscript{ki}; 
                        if (ischar(selectedPositions{ki}) && strcmp(selectedPositions{ki}, ':'))
                            selectedPositions{ki} = 1:size(this.EAz, ki);
                        elseif (islogical(selectedPositions{ki}))
                            fullidx = 1:size(this.EAz, ki);
                            selectedPositions{ki} = fullidx(selectedPositions{ki});
                        end
                    else
                        % Subscript is a mix of all remaining dimensions
                        mix = subscript{ki};
                        sizmix = size(this.EAz); sizmix = sizmix(ki:ndim);
                        if (ischar(mix) && strcmp(mix, ':'))
                            mix = 1:prod(sizmix);
                        elseif (islogical(mix))
                            fullidx = 1:prod(sizmix);
                            mix = fullidx(mix);
                        end
                        [selectedPositions{ki:ndim}] = ind2sub(sizmix, mix);                        
                        break;
                    end
                end
            end

            % Make special action if we detect we are on a special cut
            allAzAxisIndexedPositions = unique(selectedPositions{1});
            allElAxisIdxexedPositions = unique(selectedPositions{2});
            if ((length(allAzAxisIndexedPositions) == 1) && (length(allElAxisIdxexedPositions) > 1))
                % We are on vertical cut, TODO: check Az = 0° and force phi = 0° for all encountered accumulation points (Az = 0°, El = 0°)
                disp('Vertical cut detected ... should use formula one');
            elseif ((length(allAzAxisIndexedPositions) > 1) && (length(allElAxisIdxexedPositions) == 1)) 
                % We are on horizontal cut, TODO: check El = 0° and force phi = 90° for all encountered acummulation points (Az = 0°, El = 0°)
                disp('Horizontal cut detected ... should use formula two');
            else
                % Nothing we can do
                disp('Nothing special ... can only use generic formula');
            end

        end

    end

end
```

Then I can detect for cut (nb: only the first two axes are important for formula selection):

```
a = TestSubscript;

a.EPhi(:, :, 3, 1);
Nothing special ... can only use generic formula

a.EPhi(1, :, 3, 1);
Vertical cut detected ... should use formula one

a.EPhi(:, 2, 3, 1);
Horizontal cut detected ... should use formula two
```

The code block related to "*find selected positions on each dimension*" is already quite short but maybe there is more easy solution to find for all indexed positions ?